# Kendo-UI for JSP: Remote Data for Grid not loading

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to load remote data in a Grid from a SPRING Web MVC.
Here is my Controller Method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@RequestMapping(value = "/remote-data-binding/read", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String read() {

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();

    obj.put("id", "1");
    obj.put("name", "thomas");
    obj.put("decription", "erster Eintrag");

    arr.add(obj);

    obj = new JSONObject();

    obj.put("id", "2");
    obj.put("name", "Dieter");
    obj.put("decription", "zweiter Eintrag");

    arr.add(obj);       

    return arr.toJSONString();
}
```

My JSP looks like this:

```
<h2>Table/Grid Test</h2>
   <kendo:grid name="TestGrid" pageable="true" sortable="true" selectable="multiple" resizable="true" groupable="true" reorderable="true">
    <kendo:grid-columns>
        <kendo:grid-column title="Nummer" field="id" />
        <kendo:grid-column title="Name" field="name" />
        <kendo:grid-column title="Beschreibung" field="description" />
    </kendo:grid-columns>
    <kendo:dataSource pageSize="20" serverPaging="true" serverSorting="true" serverFiltering="true" serverGrouping="true">
        <kendo:dataSource-transport>                
            <kendo:dataSource-transport-read url="remote-data-binding/read.html " type="POST" contentType="application/json"/>  
            <kendo:dataSource-transport-parameterMap>
                function(options){return JSON.stringify(options);}
            </kendo:dataSource-transport-parameterMap>              
        </kendo:dataSource-transport>

    </kendo:dataSource>
    <kendo:grid-pageable input="true" numeric="false" />
</kendo:grid>
```

I checked the Response in a browser:

```
[{"decription":"erster Eintrag","name":"thomas","id":"1"},{"decription":"zweiter Eintrag","name":"Dieter","id":"2"}]
```

The Grid is not populated! Why ?

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to add a schema to the data-source, like the following example:

```
<kendo:dataSource-schema groups="data">
<kendo:dataSource-schema-model id="id">
    <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-fields>
        <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field name="name"
            type="string" />
        <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field name="location"
            type="string" />
        <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field name="description"
            type="string" />
        <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field name="imagePath"
            type="string" />
        <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field name="detailUrl"
            type="string" />
        <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field name="providerStatus"
            type="string" />
    </kendo:dataSource-schema-model-fields>
</kendo:dataSource-schema-model>
</kendo:dataSource-schema>
```

Depending on the json-structure of the response the group-property must also set correctly!